# How to insert variable as string for a web element attribute value using selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium, web-scraping, ui-automation

I am successfully able to click on the element using:

```
.FindElementByCss("[data-code^='000']", 8000).Click
```

However, I am wanting to replace the '000' with a variable assigned with the string of "000"

when I try:

```
Dim codeInList As String
codeInList = "000"
.FindElementByCss("[data-code^= 'codeInList']", 8000).Click
```

I get element not found

HTML code:

```
<div class="cell" align="center">
<a class="edit" href="Javascript:" data-code="000">
Edit</a> == $0
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed " + & + variable between the '
correct syntax:

```
.FindElementByCss("a[data-code^='" & codeInList & "']").Click
```